# дождаться результата выполнения модальной страницы

Tags: c#, xamarin, modal, maui, dialog

Пытаюсь раскурить пресловутый xamarin, и... застрял.
Суть - вызываю страницу через Navigation.PushModalAsync, и хочу дождаться результат выполнения.

пробывал:

```
private async void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    MyPage page = new MyPage();
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);

    if (page.IsFinished)
    {
        //some actions...
    }
}
```

не помогло. ради эксперимента попробывал:

```
private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    MyPage page = new MyPage();
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);

    if (page.IsFinished)
    {
        //some actions...
    }
}
```

тоже не помогло. от безвыходности попробывал:

```
private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    MyPage page = new MyPage();
    Task t =Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    t.Wait();

    if (page.IsFinished)
    {
        //some actions...
    }
}
```

и даже это не помогло. во всех случаях отладчик не дожидается выполнения модальной (диалоговой же?) страницы, а просто проверяет флаг IsFinished сразу после её открытия.
А ведь я хотел банальный аналог ShowDialog()...

Comment: `пробывал` — надо не пробывать, а делыть.

Comment: не, ну так то можно создать гидру, которая запоминает какое модальное окно открывает, переопределить OnAppearing, чтоб определить когда начальной странице возвращается фокус, и через анализ - продолжать выполнение действий. Только... чувствуете разницу в ожидаемой логике, и предлагаемой? Этот путь - явно неправильный. Хотя я практически не знаком с maui, возможно он единственный рабочий. А может и нет) в конце концов, я пишу сюда ради совета

Comment: Может вы можете подписаться на подходящее событие этой самой `page` и там уже делать что вам нужно? Да и вообще что такое `MyPage`, оно от чего-то унаследовано или это чисто ваш класс?

Comment: MyPage унаследовано от ContentPage. И да, я понимаю что можно сделать желаемое десятком разных способов, как костыльных, так и адекватных. Просто то, что модальные дотнетовские окна (страницы) не работают как модальные окна говорит о том, что я чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнём с того, что Navigation.PushModalAsync(page) просто переходит на определенную страницу, а не переходит на неё и ждёт, пока вы из неё выйдете.
Как я понял, вам надо сделать определённые действия, при выходе из страницы.
Вам просто нужно подписаться на событие Unloaded:

```
private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    MyPage page = new MyPage();
    page.Unloaded += (_,_) => 
    {
        //действия после выхода из страницы
    };
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
}
```